# How to send smileys/emoticons from Android to Spark client using XMPP

Tags: android, xmpp, smack

I am developing a chat application using `Smack` library version 4.1.5 using XMPP.

I want to send a smiley message from Android to Spark client. Currently I am using the [library](https://github.com/sharakova/EmojiTextView) for display the smileys.

If I am using XMPP to send message, my message goes in the below format

Message from phone to Spark client

`<message><body>��</body><thread>eba4f450-e90d-43c5-9879-1e0447ce2118</thread></message>`

Where as if receive the same message from Spark client I get

`<message to='test@user-pc/Smack' from='test2@user-pc/Spark' id='ow88C-36' type='chat'><thread>27uxi1</thread><inactive xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates'/></message>`

So how do I send the smiley text to Spark or any other client. What is the correct format?